# How to make multiple cart sessions on each store (Multiple Baskets on one magento login )

Tags: cart, multiple

I would like to setup a login for magento where there are mutiple baskets for the same customer.

The Logic is that customers have have many branches, they order for each branch which has its own delivery address.

Usecase
Priya logs onto magento site
Priya adds few products to default cart
Priya choses 2nd cart 
Priya adds few products to this cart
Priya checkout of 2nd cart ( but not first)

So they would have the option when logged in to select a cart and add to it

ie AAA hair London Branch, AAA hair Surrey Branch etcetra.  instead of having two logins for the main site. Each branch also has its own customer code so when the order goes into the accounting system, it needs to be mapped accordingly.

Really struggling to find how to do this using magento or offering my boss a alternative method of working that is suitable

Comment: You can simply use `multi checkout` if the case is to ship to multiple address.

Comment: Hi i thought about that but it doesn't work as they might want to just check out of one order for one address but not the other. also multi checkout makes them choose qty/ products afterwards and not before.  ie http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-multishipping-checkout/  its not going to work for us.

Comment: I have seen a non magento site do what i want and it seems to work well. Customer logs in and they have a current basket and all baskets. they can easily switch between baskets and checkout of particular baskets too.